# If the composition of a (strictly positive with compact domain) function with the logarithm is Lipschitz, then the function is Lipschitz.

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, lipschitz-functions

I'm reading a proof in which the authors want to show that a certain function $f:[0,T]\to\Bbb{R}_+\cup \{0\}$ is Lipschitz continuous. They prove that $$e^{−C|t−s|}f(t)≤f(s)≤e^{C|t−s|}f(t)$$
for all $t,s\in [0,T]$ and certain $C>0$ and then say that "the result follows".

> Why?

I don't even know that $f$ is *continuous*, *a priori*. I've tried the following: Suppose $f$ is not Lipschitz. Then there are sequences $t_n,s_n\in [0,T]$ (which I can suppose $t_n\to t\in [0,T]$ and $s_n\to s\in [0,T]$, by compactness) such that the definition of Lipschitz fails for constants, say, $e^n$, $n\in \Bbb N$, i.e. 
$$|f(t_n)-f(s_n)|>e^n|t_n-s_n|.$$
If $t\neq s$, then the inequality above says that $|f(t_n)-f(s_n)|\to +\infty$ (the images of $t_n,s_n$ by $f$ get arbitrarily far). But then... what? And what if $t=s$? Then I can't say if $e^n|t_n-s_n|\to 0$ or $+\infty$. Furthermore, I have the difficult of working with $f$ without knowing anything about its continuity...

*Remark.:* If I knew that $f>0$ (*strictly* positive), then applying the logarithm the proven inequality would be equivalent to
$$|\ln (f(t))-\ln (f(s))|\leq C|t-s|.$$
This is not exactly the case (since $f$ can be zero) but I've used this as motivation to the title of this post.

Edit: I've just realized that if $f(t)=0$ for some $t\in [0,T]$, then the proven inequality says that $0\leq f(s)\leq 0$, for any $s\in [0,T]$ and therefore $f\equiv 0$. So we can indeed suppose that $f>0$ as stated in the title.

Comment: If the function is positive over a compact domain (closed and bounded) and the composition with a logarithm is Lipschitz then the original function attains its supremum by the Extreme Value Theorem.

Comment: Assume that $f(t)=0$ for some $t\in[0,T]$. So, for any $s\in[0,T]$ the value $f(s)$ is ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I guess a more elegant approach is to consider that the composition of two Lipschitz functions (with adequate domains) is once again Lipschitz.

Since you've shown $\log \circ f$ is Lipschitz, it is in particular bounded above on compact intervals.
Now, $\exp$ had bounded derivative on intervals that are bounded above, and is hence Lipschitz on such intervals.
It follows that the composition $\exp\circ \big(\log \circ f\big) = f$ is Lipschitz.

---

Since $f>0$, we have

$$e^{-C(t-s)} \leqslant \frac{f(s)}{f(t)} \leqslant e^{C(t-s)}$$

Then, letting $s\to t$ we find by the squeeze thereom that

$$\lim_{s\to t}\frac{f(s)}{f(t)} = 1\implies \lim_{s\to t}f(s) = f(t),$$

from which the continuity of $f$ follows.
Hence, by the Extreme Value Theorem $f$ atains some positive maximum $M$.
Moreover, for all $t\in[0,T)$ and $h$ with $0<h\leqslant T-t$ we have

$$\underbrace{\left(\frac{e^{-Ch}-1}h\right)}_{<0} f(t)\leqslant\frac{f(t+h)-f(t)}h\leqslant \underbrace{\left(\frac{e^{Ch}-1}h\right)}_{>0} f(t)$$

Hence:

\begin{align}
\frac{|f(t+h)-f(t)|}h
&\leqslant
\max\left\{\frac{1-e^{-Ch}}h, \frac{e^{Ch}-1}h\right\}\cdot f(t)
\end{align}

Now, $f\leqslant M$, $\left(e^{Ch}-1\right)/h$ is increasing over $h>0$, and $\left(1-e^{-Ch}\right)/h$ is decreasing over $h>0$.
Since

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1-e^{-Ch}}h = -\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{e^{-Ch}-1}h
= -\left(\left.\frac{d}{dx}\,e^{-Cx}\right)\right|_{x=0} = C,$$

it follows that

\begin{align}
\frac{|f(t+h)-f(t)|}h
&\leqslant
M\cdot\max\left\{C, \frac{e^{CT}-1}T\right\},
\end{align}

which conludes the proof.

Comment: Your edit is really elegant! Thanks

Comment: De nada. :) Glad to help!